# How do I automatically close the netrw pane after having executed :Vexplore and opened a file in a new buffer?

Tags: vim, netrw

**What happens now**: When I'm in Vim, and execute the `:Vexplore` command, a new pane appears where can I browse files using `netrw`. When I open a file in the `netrw` pane, it opens in the right pane (so not in the `netrw` pane) like I configured it using `let g:netrw_browse_split = 4`.

**What I would like to happen**:
However, I would like the `netrw` pane to close immediately after the new file is opened in the right pane. Is that possible?

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/g4vakc/automatically_closing_netrw_window_after_vex/fnzwiod?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) comment on Reddit mentions the use of an autocommand, but I'm not familiar enough with vim scripts in order to create that unfortunately.

Comment: ```let g:netrw_browse_split = 4```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that opening a file in a new buffer and closing the netrw pane is actually the same as opening a file in a netrw pane. And this is by default.

So make sure you have

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 0
```

in your .vimrc and open netrw using `:Ex`, which will open netrw in current pane.

Comment: Thanks. This would be a valid answer if netrw were to open in the left pane like it's the case with NERDTree, which isn't the case here. In this case, the netrw pane takes the whole pane space.